# xamarin how to show multiple column grid which support both andriod and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid, cross-platform

I want to create a list view with four column, first two column will have text and next two column will have clickable button(image). Number of rows is not fixed- so data binding is require. Should support android and iOS. please suggest which xamarin control will be best suited for me.

Can i use data template as shown in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/

or should use Grid, Grid layout or any other.

======== Solution Applied=============

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewExpenses" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="40">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--<Label x:Name="idLabel" Text="{Binding Id}"/>-->
                <Label x:Name="textLabel1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <!--<Button x:Name="btnEdit" Image="icon.png" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"  Grid.Column="2" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  Clicked="OnEditClicked" />-->
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                    <Image Source="EditRed.png" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
    Tapped="OnEditTapped" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>`enter code here`
```

=====================================
Thanks,

@paul

Comment: I assume you mean "iOS", not "ISO", which is the International Standards Organization.

Comment: if you want a databound grid control, you'll need to use a 3rd party control.  There are several free and commercial ones available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the number of rows is not fixed but each row will look the same, I would suggest a List View with an inline data template.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating/

Comment: Will it support both Andriod and iOS

Comment: Yes it will support both iOS and Android.

Comment: Updated the question with solution that is applied and working fine, please suggest me if any changes require.

Comment: The only thing I would do differently is in the TapGestureRecogniser - I'd bind to a Command in the view model rather than using OnEditTapped in the code behind. I try and avoid any code in the code behind if possible to make a cleaner separation of concerns and make the app more testable.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, i will do as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Data templates you mentioned is required in case of different row views. For your case Grid should be sufficient. You can add rows dynamically for example like shown here

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42393/need-to-add-rows-dynamically-in-a-grid

If that doesn't work you can use ListView with custom cells

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/

Comment: Can't use a grid as the number of rows is not fixed.

Comment: Why are you suggesting custom cells? I can't see the need.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne As you know DataTemplate IS custom cell. I think we are suggesting the same thing. I just don't call it DataTemplate as it implies to have at least couple for DataTemplate selection.